# What Font does the logo of Soundtracker.com Use

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Trying to determine which font is used in this logo:

[image: Logo image]

Anyone have a good eye?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just good ol' Century Gothic Bold. Comes with MS Office, or you can buy it here:
http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=165757

Comment: IMO, there are much nicer fonts with a similar style.

Comment: CG has pointed mitre joins on N, M, W, V etc. The E's middle bar is full width. Also, in CG, the K's diagonals join at the vertical. The R in CG, like the K, almost joins the vertical.